# Run cmd and install framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cmd

I want to run my app on another PC. But if there's not installed .net 3.5 I can't run it. I found solution to run `cmd` and detect whether its 3.5 or not. If not it will start install.
but if I start my app there just start `cmd` but without my argument that is `if exist \"%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v3.5\" goto end start /wait .\\Framework\\dotnetfx.exe /q /norestart\`. and then I want to close immediately `cmd` . Any suggestions?

```
public class CmdRun
{
    public CmdRun()
    {
        string cmdMessage ="if exist \"%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v3.5\" goto end start /wait .\\Framework\\dotnetfx.exe /q /norestart\" :end";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",cmdMessage);
    }

    public static void CmdRunFunc()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "if exist \"%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v3.5\" goto end start /wait .\\Framework\\dotnetfx.exe /q /norestart\" :end";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aehm, if NET is not installed there is no way to run a NET app, whatever this app does.

Comment: You can't write a program in .NET which installs .NET - I think this is pretty obvious :) Means, if .net is not installed then your "installer" program just won't be able to run, since it is .net which runs it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you let your application always start through the cmd script, no matter what? That way you don't have the issue of your program requiring .NET to be able to install .NET...

Comment: Note, that's what "installers" are for - they install everything a program needs to run (in your case, .NET). Note that you can create installer in Visual Studio (see e.g. "Publish" tab in project settings). Take a look here: Deploying the .NET Applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e.aspx

Comment: Yeah i see now. Im trying it now with that publisher hope it will work . But i wanted to start my app just simply from my .exe . I Wanted to start my app kinda simply if u know what i mean .. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative Solution:

Go to `Solution Explorer > Right Click your project > Properties > Publish > Prerequisites > Choose .NET 3.5 and then choose to download automatically.`

Then Publish your Application ( `Build > Publish - Solution Name` )

This will force the application to download and install .NET 3.5.

Comment: theres no download automatically. its just "from the component vendor's web sit","from the same location", "following location" no automatics

Comment: Component vendor's website option will download .NET 3.5 from Microsoft's Website.

Answer (score 2):

This code is quite useless. If it runs, it means that .NET is already installed, so there' no need to check for it anymore.

You should probably just make a batch file that does the check and either launches the .NET installer or launches the app. Something along these lines:

```
if exist \"%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v3.5\" goto end 
start /wait .\\Framework\\dotnetfx.exe /q /norestart\" 
:end
start .\\myapp.exe
```